# How do I get the existing schedules and edit the trigger on quartz.net?

Tags: c#, .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, job-scheduling

How can I get the existing schedules from quartz.net and edit one of the triggers firing time? Please advice. I am new to quartz.net and there is nothing exmplained about this in Quartz.net documentation.

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like this

```
var allTriggerKeys = sched.GetTriggerKeys(GroupMatcher<TriggerKey>.AnyGroup());
foreach (var triggerKey in allTriggerKeys)
{
    ITrigger trigger = sched.GetTrigger(triggerKey);
    if(trigger.JobName=="yourtriggername", trigger.JobGroup=="yourjobgroupname")
       {
            scheduler.RescheduleJob(trigger.JobName, trigger.JobGroup, trigger);
       }
}
```